# Как сделать запрос в базу данных, возвращающий кастомные поля?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Перечитывая документацию так и не нашел как сделать подобный запрос в базу данных. Прошу помощи у более опытных товарищей.

Repository:

```
    public interface QWagonRepository extends CrudRepository<QWagon, Integer> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT stock.wagon, stock.product, product.title, product.price, stock.count, stock.selled 
        from stock, product
        where stock.product = product.id and stock.wagon = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
        List<QWagon> GetWagon(Integer wagon);
    }
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class QWagon {
    @Column(name = "wagon")
    Integer wagon_id;
    @Column(name = "product")
    Integer product_id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    String product;
    @Column(name = "price")
    Double price;
    @Column(name = "count")
    Integer count;
    @Column(name = "selled")
    Integer selled;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Stock Entity

```
@Entity
public class Stock {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EStock eStock;
    private Integer count;
    private Integer selled;
}
```

Product entity

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private Integer tag;
    private String unit;
}
```

[image: Модель бд]

Comment: @EmbeddedId в Stock это как я понимаю композитный идентификатор?

Comment: @EdgarAsatryan Да, все верно.